# Button suspenders airport firendly

Tags: air-travel

Anyone know where I can buy Button airport friendly suspenders? I know there are several clip on brands but need the button suspenders that are airport friendly.

Comment: What do you mean by "airport friendly"? No metal?

Comment: I can't see what would make a button suspender airport unfriendly.  Even the small amount of metal in the adjustment clips would not be a headache only perhaps a quick wanding after walking through the metal detector.

Comment: @Tom Indeed.  All the suspenders I've ever worn had far less metal in then than my previous pair of eyeglasses.  But I've never worn them though airport security!

Comment: On terminology, the UK English uses the word 'braces' for what you want, in British English 'suspenders' are something a woman wears.  I went to amazon.co.uk and searched 'mens braces with buttons' and got page after page of them. Prices started at about GBP 6.

Answer (score 1):

If you search Google (or your favorite search engine) you'll find a ton of results for "[airport friendly suspenders](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B005UO0XUI)" (that's the first non-sponsored link) or "[airport friendly braces](http://www.mensbraces.com.au/airport-friendly-braces/)" (same again, braces is UK English for suspenders). These have plastic buttons and so will not trigger the metal detector alarm.

But, wearing normal braces/suspenders is perfectly OK. Airport staff are used to that and the worst that will happen is you'll get a secondary search where they use the handheld metal detectors to confirm that you don't have any other metal on your body.

I seem to recall there was a Kickstarter (or similar) for non-metal suspenders/braces but I can't find it and, as I've shown above, there are plenty of other options.